# How to train Tesseract with a font where letters _may be_ connected to each other

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Imagine a font where certain letters can be connected to each other, e.g., S and T connected as shown in the image below.

[image]

What's the best way to teach Tesseract how to recognize this kind of text?  With some of the guides I saw, user is asked to individually name the letters.  However, I am not sure how that would work in the case of say "S", "T" and "I", since S-and-T are connected, whereas S-and-I are not connected.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work, but could you just say "ST" is a new "letter", while having "S" and "I" their own letters?

Comment: Probably not .. my goal is to match the word "STANDINGS" in the image to confirm that this _IS_ indeed the image I am looking for.  So, not sure how having a new letter called "ST" can help.

Comment: Ignore "some of the guides" - follow official training https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesstrain

Comment: @user898678 is there a specific section in the guide or a technique you would suggest?